# Django rest framework CRUD API for model with foriegn key elements

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, crud, django-serializer

Okay so here I am with another problem I'm facing with Django. This time it's the REST framework.

I have a Model with Foreign Key dependencies in my project. I had to retrieve the foreign key field as an object, not just an ID field and was successful in that using [Serializer Relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

So my **Serializer.py** looks like:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = EventUserSerializer(read_only=False)
    severity = EventSeveritySerializer(read_only=False)
    type = EventTypeSerializer(read_only=False)
    cause = EventCauseSerializer(read_only=False)
    subcause = EventSubcauseSerializer(read_only=False)
    impact = EventImpactSerializer(read_only=False)
    point_location = PointLocationSerializer(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'owner', 'status', 
            'severity', 'type', 'cause', 'subcause', 'impact', 
            'is_public', 'occurrence_time', 'reporting_agency', 
            'estimated_duration', 'confirmed_timestamp', 
            'rejected_timestamp', 'closed_timestamp', 'point_location', )
```

Making a GET request, I get the result I wanted:

```
{
    "meta": {
    "count": 1,
    "previous": null,
    "next": null
},
"results": [
{
    "id": 8,
    "description": "test event 1",
    "owner": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "venus",
            "email": "venus.saini@ibigroup.com"
        }
    },
    "status": "confirmed",
    "severity": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:27:24.722000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:27:24.723000Z",
        "name": "Severe",
        "is_enabled": true,
        "sortorder": 1
    },
    "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:27:45.203000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:27:45.204000Z",
        "name": "Accident",
        "event_category": "unplanned",
        "sortorder": 2
    },
    "cause": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:28:16.088000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:28:16.092000Z",
        "name": "Whether Conditions",
        "sortorder": 3,
        "event_type": 2
    },
    "subcause": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:28:28.475000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:28:28.478000Z",
        "name": "Slippery",
        "display_name": "Slippery",
        "sortorder": 4,
        "cause": 2
    },
    "impact": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:28:40.599000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:28:40.599000Z",
        "name": "All Lanes Blocked",
        "sortorder": 5
    },
    "is_public": false,
    "occurrence_time": "2016-08-25T06:34:13Z",
    "reporting_agency": "",
    "estimated_duration": null,
    "confirmed_timestamp": "2016-08-25T06:34:15Z",
    "rejected_timestamp": "2016-08-25T06:34:16Z",
    "closed_timestamp": "2016-08-25T06:34:18Z",
    "point_location": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2016-08-24T07:18:03.017000Z",
        "modified": "2016-08-24T07:18:03.018000Z",
        "roadway_name": "Northbound",
        "direction": "North",
        "is_primary": false,
        "cross_street_name": "test street 1",
        "offset": "After",
        "distance": 3,
        "is_forward": false
    }
 }]
 }
```

The problem I face is while using the POST request. I don't know how that would work so I found [this link](http://www.erol.si/2015/09/django-rest-framework-nestedserializer-with-relation-and-crud/). It looks like it has the solution; I mean this is exactly what I want to accomplish [passing the ID of the foreign key element makes the object entry]. But I keep getting random errors like `super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_relation'`.

Can somebody please guide me to how I should be doing it? I'm using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test my APIs.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Using PUT/POST without the CustomSerializer gives me error 415:

```
{
  "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain;charset=UTF-8\" in request."
}
```

Comment: Here is a chapter about writing nested objects: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: About the error: make sure postman uses application/json media type

Comment: thanks @RadosławGanczarek That error is gone. Now I'm getting `"This field is required."` for every field of foreign key related model

Comment: How does your payload look like?

Comment: How are you trying to post data? AngularJS? ReactJS? AJAX? Postman? If angular check your Content-Type header. It should be "application/json". Also look for your DRF parser settings.

Comment: I'm using Postman @UmutGunebakan I'm not able to figure out how to make POST request.

Comment: @VenuSaini I am using Postman 4.5.1. When using POST method click on the "raw" data type on "Body". Enter your JSON data, then select media type as "JSON(application/json)". By default it is "Text". Also it is located on right (5th dropdown after binary). If this does not work, check your default parsers in DRF settings.